# What is Difference Between .Core CLR VS Mono CLR? Then why Microsoft maintain run time environments?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, mono, clr, coreclr

What is Difference Between .Core CLR VS Mono CLR? Then why Microsoft maintain different run time environments ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are implementations of the .NET Standard but they have different implementation details. [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono) is historically grown by the need of a cross-platform .NET implementation that runs everywhere. Later Mono became the foundation for Xamarin.

[.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) is designed for performance, cross-platform, scalable cloud scenarios and the main workload is [ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore) that runs on it. It's true that both are similar in the API surface and cross-platform capabilities, but they were created with other requirements in mind.

Both framework implementations are well supported. Depending on what you need to do, you pick one of them:

**.NET Core**

- ASP.NET Core (Web Apps)
- Desktop Apps WPF, WF (.NET Core 3.0 and Windows only)
- Console Apps

**Mono**

- Games (with Unity)
- Console Apps
- Desktop Apps (e.g. GTK#, cross-platform)
- Mobile Apps (Android, iOS)

Comment: Some addition, 1) Mono supports more gaming frameworks than Unity (MonoGame for instance). 2) Mono also supports more operating systems, https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/ 3) Mono enables Blazor (WebAssembly). 4) .NET 5 is the future, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/